# Chain guard for a belt-drive bike?

Tags: belt-drive

So this morning I'm riding to work on my shiny new tourer, when my trouser leg gets caught in the Gates belt drive. Not good!

I'd rather not go the leg-strap route if I can avoid it, which leads me to ask whether a chain guard or chainring guard exists that would fit over a belt, given that the belt is wider than a chain. The crank is a Shimano Tiagra, if that matters.

Comment: What do you have against the leg strap, if I might ask?

Comment: Mostly the I-will-inevitably-misplace-it factor. :) Something attached to the bike is a lot more likely to be there when I need it than something I have to attach to me.

Comment: Tuck your trousers into your socks?

Comment: Get a velcro strap.  When you take it off, velcro it around the handlebar (or to a pannier strap, etc).  I lose all sorts of stuff, but have 20-year-old leg straps.

Comment: My Spot Ajax has a belt guard, and I love it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are chainguards that work with derailleur bikes. Your belt might be wider than a chain, but it isn't wider than a triple :-)
Something like http://www.sjscycles.co.uk/hebie-chainguard-for-triple-ring-systems-with-a-48t-outer-ring-prod19993/
(If you've got a 52t chainring, it might be trickier to find something that will fit.)

Comment: A chain guard designed for a single speed or hub geared bike will be neater, and I suspect many will fit over a belt. But I can't point to a specific one of them that I know will fit with a belt (and there are some I'm fairly sure won't).

Answer (score 1):

The tight roll was popular when I was a teen. It's less fashionable but infinitely more useful now. You just fold over the cuff of your pants and then roll them a time or two. Super easy and nothing to keep track of.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tight_rolled_pants